# How to read an Excel file while it's being written to?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, file-io

I'm using Python for scraping names and phone numbers from a website. I use pandas to write to an Excel file.

All works fine but I want to figure out how to read the file while it's being written, since it takes hours to finish writing contacts from 1000 page and the file only appears in my folder once the program finishes scraping all thepages specified.

My code looks like this :

```
list=[]

for contact in contacts:

    name = result.find_element_by_xpath('.//div/h2').text
    phone=result.find_element_by_xpath('.//ul[@class="phone"]/li')[0].text

    list.append((name, phone))

df = pd.DataFrame(list, columns=['Name', 'Telephone'])
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandasS.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: Short answer: You can't read an excel file as it is being written.  At least, not unless you segregate the saving to be in parts, where you might run into permission issues as you have the file open and your code is trying to write over it.  Either way I doubt the bottleneck here is your `xlsxwriter`, but the parsing of `contacts`.  You might periodically dump your results as you loop through `contacts` to ensure you have the correct info if that's what you want to do.

Comment: Also, don't use `list` as an object name.  It'll shadow the built-in `list` object and causes subsequent lines to fail, e.g. `list(...)` will throw an error.  Name it differently like `lst = []` or `my_list = []` etc.

Comment: An alternative is you might use `xlwings` module to write into an open Excel in real time (since it seems you have limited info to be written per parse through), so you can see the info updated in real time.  But that's a huge caveat as you might lose info before a successful save, and data might get inadvertently updated on the front end, overwriting the script results.

Comment: i appreciate your help, in fact it s exactly what i want but Excel crashes after filling 3 rows

Comment: Are you crashing from `xlwings`? If so yeah I can see, since it adds a dependency to Excel's responsiveness for writing real time, and you end up losing the progress as I mentioned.  The `xlsxwriter` method looks fine, you'll just need to wait it out, or dump it out in chunks.

Comment: excel crashes after getting 3 lines filled, 
fault module name: KERNELBASE.dll .
my code looks like this : 
`df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["nom", "telephone"])

wb = xw.Book()

sht = wb.sheets[0]

list_of_contacts =driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="particuliers"]/ol/li')

for contact in list_of_contact:

    df.loc[len(df)] = [name,telephone]

    sht.range('A1').value = df`